# Problem where real-time data transmitted from mobile is actually received late

Tags: android

What causes real-time data transmitted from Android to actually be received 3 or 20 days later, and what is this phenomenon called?
As far as I know, this phenomenon also occurs with game data.
Am I the only one experiencing this?

For example, when 10 pieces of data are transmitted from an Android phone, the actual server data received is 9 pieces, and the remaining data takes several days to arrive.
For example, when 10 pieces of data are transmitted from an Android phone, the actual server data received is 9 pieces, and the remaining data takes several days to arrive.

This doesn't happen often, but it does happen. I'm curious about people experiencing the same phenomenon as me.

I want to know this problem.